# Looking for '70s era Time Traveling Young Adult Novel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, young-adult, prehistoric

I vividly recall this book I read when I was a kid in the '70s.

I thought it was called Saturday the 14th, but I am having no luck with that title.

It's about an adolescent girl having a really bad day that culminates in her finding her brother reading her diary aloud to a friend of his.

She runs away and sits by a tree, and ends up traveling back in time to probably the late stone age, I know there's language because it's a pivotal plot point when she starts speaking their language.

I don't recall much of the middle part, I know she starts her period, which involves some ritual in this culture. I want to say she spends a year and a half there and when she comes back it's the same day, no one has noticed she was gone, and there's some kind of resolution with a conflict with a teacher -- basically, she's matured.

I cannot find any sign of this on the internet. It's rare that I recall a book so vividly and would love to get my hands on a copy for the kids in my life.

Comment: Shades of *A Wrinkle In Time* and *A Swiftly Tilting Planet*, but neither fits.

Answer (score 16):

You can search for titles of SF stories on the [Internet Speculative Fiction Database (ISFDB)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi). Browsing the search results for `Saturday` turns up [*Saturday, the Twelfth of October*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?16491), a novel by [Norma Fox Mazer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norma_Fox_Mazer) published in 1975. Judging by [the blurb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0440995922), this looks like the right book:

> After spending almost a year with cave people from an earlier time, a young girl is transported back to the present greatly changed, both by her experience and by the fact that no one believes her.